# Как отключить phpunit тесты в Travis Ci?

Tags: phpunit, непрерывная-интеграция, travis

Мой PHP проект пока не использует никакие автотесты, когда я делаю build с простым travis.yml файлом, то он фейлится с ошибкой "The command "phpunit" exited with 2."

```
language: php
sudo: required

php:
  - '5.4'

notifications:
  email:
    recipients:
      - example@mail.com

dist: trusty

install:
  - true
# Building Specific Branches

branches:
# safelist
  only:
  - dev
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно документации Travis для [PHP](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/#Default-Test-Script):

> The default test script is phpunit.
>
> If your project uses something other than PHPUnit, you can override
>   our default test command to be anything you want.

Для этого вы можете изменить [значение `script` в файле конфигурации](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Customizing-the-Build-Step):

```
script:
- do something
- do something else
```